# Map custom route in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have such route mapping in Global.ascx:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "Help", // Route name
               "Help", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Help", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

So when user typed http://mysite.com/Help he will get a response From `Home.Help` action.

But if i try to call that route with parameter `id=something` http://mysite.com/Help/something
I am getting an error `The resource cannot be found.`

How could i fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an `{id}` route value token in the URL pattern of the route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Help", // Route name
    "Help/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Help", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```